# Blender - Lagging during duplication

Tags: modeling

I keep trying to duplicate the highlighted faces of the model shown in image 1. I get the desired results, as seen in image 2. However, when I drag the duplicated array of faces with my mouse, it lags. It takes longer for the object to be dragged to my desired location than it should take. The duplicate even lags when I try to scale it. This makes it difficult to create my 3D model.

I wasn't having this issue until I started this process.

I've researched various methods for reducing this lag, like altering certain settings in my preferences that might be affecting the rendering process (see image 3), but that hasn't helped. I even installed the most recent version of Blender (3.5), but I'm still getting the same result.

From what I've heard, the issue may be with the Graphical Processing Unit. So far, I'm only working with the model; no color or light. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can reduce this lag? Also, can you point out why the software lags when performing the process I previously described?

Note: I wasn't having this issue before.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

[image: Image 3]

[image]

Comment: You have a very high viewport setting (5) on your Subdivision modifier. What happens if you reduce it to the same level (2) as the Render setting?

Comment: I lowered my viewport setting along with other settings in preferences and it didn’t make a difference

Comment: No idea in that case. I suggest sharing your Blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there so that we can look at your settings directly and see if it happens here.

Comment: I just uploaded the file to blend-exchange.

Comment: You need to edit your question and insert the link on the blend-exchange upload page into it as it says on that page otherwise we won't be able to download it!

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=BzyRjJ9k" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/BzyRjJ9k/)

Comment: I've added that link into your question as I suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my original comment, you had a very high <kbd>Levels Viewport</kbd> setting (5) on your <kbd>Subdivision</kbd> modifier which is causing the lag:

[image]

Reduce it to the same value as the Render setting (2) and the lag disappears:

[image]

Comment: As mentioned previously, I lowered the levels viewpoint and nothing changed. But I'll try again.

Comment: If it doesn't work, I respond back.

Comment: It worked. Can explain how setting the viewport higher than 2 caused lag?

Comment: I'm no expert on the internal workings of Blender but I assume it's because of the amount of extra calculations that have to be done as you move the object when you have a much higher vertex density due to the modifier setting. There really isn't any point in setting the viewport level higher than the render one as the render setting is the one that's used for the final image. I normally use a setting of 2 for the viewport and can't recall ever using higher than 3 for a simple object like your barrel.

Comment: Thanks for your help, and thanks for the response.

Comment: Just a quick additional comment: If you take the blend file you posted and look at the details of the object in the bottom status bar you'll see that there are 2560 vertices with 96 selected. Apply the modifier with your settings back in Object mode and the figures change to around 1,295,000 with 66,560 selected!